# The type signature for "effect" lacks an accompanying binding

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble wrapping my head around my function. It calls a function "drawSpecialCard" that returns a random number. Now, I've read about this error and I know its a problem of something being unimplemented but i have no idea what to do. Im not very bright when it comes to Haskell.

```
import System.Random

drawSpecialCard :: IO Int
drawSpecialCard = randomRIO(1,16)

effect :: [Char]
effect = do
let cardNo = drawSpecialCard
 return $ case cardNo of
               1 -> "Pay"
               2 -> "ToJail"
               3 -> "Collect"
               4 -> "GoBack"    
               5 -> "moveOn"
```

Answer (score 1):

In `do` blocks, `let` defines but does not run IO actions. You want something like

```
effect :: IO [Char]
effect = do
  cardNo <- drawSpecialCard
  return $ case cardNo of
      ...
```

Note that `effect` must return `IO` as well.

Comment: It solved the binding error but now it says it has a parse error on the arrows of the case sentences